# NPE on getStringArray

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I'm having problems to get an array of colors.
I get a NullPointerException while I fetch the data from the file `strings.xml`.
The Logcat reports a NPE in this line:

```
colorList.add(Color.parseColor(colore));
```

strings.xml

```
 <array name="colors">
 <item>#FFFFFF</item>
    <item >#FFFFF0</item>
    <item >#FFFFE0</item>
    <item >#FFFF00</item>
 </array>
```

Adapter

```
public class ColorPickerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public ColorPickerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

String colors[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // add the color array to the list
        for(String colore : colors){
                colorList.add(Color.parseColor(colore));
        }
}
```

Comment: You can't initialize an object at declaration level. Replace this `private List<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` with `private List<Integer> colorList;`

Comment: And... why don't you use `colors.xml` to store colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<string-array name="colors">
    <item>#FFFFFF</item>
    <item>#FFFFF0</item>
    <item>#FFFFE0</item>
    <item>#FFFF00</item>
  </string-array>
```

use `string-array` instead of **array**.